# MYSQL Update two tables with their values

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to achieve the following:

If you get an empty FIELD1 in Table A, get the value of FIELD2 in Table B where FIELD1 is empty.

Then put ID from TABLE A in FIELD1 in TABLE B.

But I dont't know how to start this for the whole Table A.

**Before:**

TABLE A:

```
ID  FIELD1 FIELD2
1          RANDOM VALUE
2          RANDOM VALUE
3          RANDOM VALUE
```

TABLE B:

```
ID  FIELD1 FIELD2
1   1234   XXXXXXXXXXXX
2          XXXXXXXXXXXX
3          XXXXXXXXXXXX
4   5678   XXXXXXXXXXXX
5          XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**After:**

TABLE A:

```
ID  FIELD1        FIELD2
1   XXXXXXXXXXXX  RANDOM VALUE
2   XXXXXXXXXXXX  RANDOM VALUE
3   XXXXXXXXXXXX  RANDOM VALUE
```

TABLE B:

```
ID  FIELD1 FIELD2
1   1234   XXXXXXXXXXXX
2   1      XXXXXXXXXXXX
3   2      XXXXXXXXXXXX
4   5678   XXXXXXXXXXXX
5   3      XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by enumerating the values in each table.  So, start with table b:

```
set @rn := 0;

update b
    set field1 = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where b.field1 is null
    order by b.id;
```

Now that you have this information, go through a similar process for a:

```
set @rn := 0;
update a join
       (select a.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
        from a
        where a.field1 is null
        order by a.id
       ) aa
       on a.id = aa.id join
       b
       on a.seqnum = b.field1
    set a.field1 = b.field2;
```

A major caveat with this process:  it assumes that the new sequential numbers do not conflict with the existing numbers.  There are tricks that you can use to avoid problems.  For instance, you can enumerate the values as negative numbers (subtracting 1), if all existing values are positive.  The rest of the logic will work.